# How do I obtain a duplicate bike key for my kryptonite U lock?

Tags: lock

I want a duplicate key for my Kryptonite U-lock. I have the key number.

Where can I order an additional key that will work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  not really sure what the question is.

Comment: Grammatically, this is not a question, but my wild guess is that he meant to ask how to get a replacement key for Kryptonite lock. Just googling for those words finds the answer, but I guess it feels better to just write "I want" to a Q&A site.

Comment: @mattnz Looks like OP is a new user, so may not be familiar with the site.   It would be completely acceptable to tweak the question.

Comment: That link (https://shop.kryptonitelock.com/atpo_order_forms/order-keys.html?origin=en.html) or any link on Kryptonite site for replacing keys has not worked for weeks now, as far as I can tell (as of 2022-02-22): Website says "Dear Kryptonite Customer, Unfortunately we are experiencing outages on both our ATPO and Key Services pages. We are working hard to remedy the situation. We appreciate your patience and apologize for any inconvenience."

Answer (score 10):

You can get another key for your lock by [ordering it from Kryptonite at this link.](https://shop.kryptonitelock.com/atpo_order_forms/order-keys.html?origin=en.html)